# Fullpage.js: Adding "active" Class to Slide Anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, fullpage.js

http://codepen.io/theandrewwest/pen/pDEIo

I'm using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js?codekitCB=409265653.906910#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex) and have a section with a submenu that navigates through horizontal slides. I want to add an "active" class to the anchor corresponding to the active slide. I know the functionality is built in for navigating vertical sections using the "menu" option, and I have that working for the main nav, but it looks like I'll need to use a callback to add the class to anchors linked to horizontal slides.

I know just enough JS to get plugins working the way I want, but I'm not sure of the best way to set this up. I'm linking to the slides using "data-index" in the pen, but I plan on using custom anchors once I can get them working (no problem with sections, I just can't get them working for slides). I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: So simply you want to add active class to element which you are clicking right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I added a working example at http://codepen.io/theandrewwest/pen/fltAE.

Comment: I would recommend you to add the code of the initialization with the callback rather than just adding a link to the codepen site. That's usually the way to operate here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of the plugin. If you take a look at the [living demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage/1) you will realize how it adds the active class by default to the active slide. Just check it with firebug or Chrome inspector.

Comment: The active class was being added to the active slide itself, but I needed a way to target the anchor linked to the active slide.